# How to use IFixture.Build<T>() with AutoMoqCustomization when T is an interface?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq, autofixture

I have an interface with some read-only properties:

```
interface IItem
{
    string Name { get; }
    // ... more properties
}
```

With `Fixture.Create()` method I can create a single mocked interface instance using the `AutoMoqCustomization` like so:

```
var fixture = new Fixture();
fixture.Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());

var mockedItem = fixture.Create<IItem>();
```

But to create a list of those interface instances with `Fixture.Build().CreateMany()`, I cannot do it just by doing the following:

```
var mockedItems = fixture
    .Build<IItem>()
    .With(x => x.Name, "Abc")
    .CreateMany();
```

The reason that I need `Build()` is that I want to have a certain return value for a certain property, and leave the rest of the properties to be still auto-generated. But unfortunately, according to the documentation, when using `Build()` all the customizations on the Fixture is bypassed.

I am using the following versions: AutoFixture 4.8.0, AutoFixture.AutoMoq 4.8.0 and Moq 4.9.0.

Is there a simple way to achieve this without having to define my own `ISpecimenBuilder`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mock can be extracted from the object and configured

```
var mockedItems = fixture.CreateMany<IItem>(3);

foreach (var item in mockedItems) {
    Mock<IItem> mock = Mock.Get(item);
    mock.Setup(_ => _.Name).Returns("Abc");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the idiomatic way to do this in Autofixture (without creating your own implementation of `ISpecimenBuilder`) would be to rely on the ability to customize the Mock specimen that gets created in order to provide the `IItem` specimen:

```cs
var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
fixture.Customize<Mock<IItem>>(c => c.OmitAutoProperties()
                                     .Do(m => m.SetupGet(i => i.Name).Returns("Abc")));

var items = fixture.CreateMany<IItem>(3);
Assert.That(items.Select(i => i.Name), Is.All.EqualTo("Abc"));
```

It's admittedly not as terse as customizing the item *after* retrieving it, but it does allow you to keep the setup of the specimen separate from its creation, which can be beneficial if you need to reuse that specimen for other specimens that should be created by autofixture.