# How do you set some properties and leave others as defaults using AutoFixture and AutoMoqCustomization?

Tags: moq, xunit, autofixture

I am new to **AutoFixture** so I hope you can help. How do you set some properties in an object but leave others as the AutoFixture default - *while using XUnit's [Theory] attribute and an AutoDataAttribute*.

For example, in the contrived Airport example below based on Jason Robert's Pluralsight course, when setting the property (or the Airport object) e.g.

`f.Customize<Mock<IAirport>>(c => c.Do(m => m.SetupGet(i => i.code).Returns("NOO")));`

the other properties are often null, or I have to manually set them rather than letting AutoFixture do it.  I would prefer to have cleaner code where the fixtureFactory sets all the properties for the Airport so that the V2 unit test only passed in a single Airport parameter.

So, within the fixtureFactory

- How do you set MULTIPLE properties?
- How does one use the default AutoFixture values rather than leaving the uninitialized values as
  null?

Thanks!

```
using AutoFixture;
using AutoFixture.AutoMoq;
using AutoFixture.Xunit2;
using Moq;
using System;
using Xunit;
namespace AirportTesterWithAutoFixture
{
    public interface IAirport
    {
        string city { get; set; }
        string code { get; set; }
        string country { get; set; }
        string name { get; set; }

        void CallAirTrafficControl();
    }
    public class Airport : IAirport
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string code { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
        public Airport()
        {
        }
        public Airport(string name, string code, string country, string city)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.code = code;
            this.country = country;
            this.city = city;
        }
        public void CallAirTrafficControl()
        {
            if (this.country.Equals("Canada") && this.code.StartsWith("Y"))
            {
                // Send "Bonjour!"();
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Invalid code for Canada");
            }
        }
    }
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [Fact]
        public void V1_Validate_ExceptionThrown_ForInvalidCanadianAirportCode()
        {
            var fixture = new Fixture();
            var sut = fixture.Create<Airport>();
            // Overwrite code and country with invalid setting for Canada.
            sut.country = "Canada";
            sut.code = "NOT";
            Assert.ThrowsAny<Exception>(() => sut.CallAirTrafficControl());
        }
        [Theory]
        [AutoMoqInvalidAirportDataAttribute]
        public void V2_Validate_ExceptionThrown_ForInvalidCanadianAirportCode(IAirport sut, string name, string city)
        {
            Airport airport = new Airport(name, sut.code, sut.country, city);
            Assert.ThrowsAny<Exception>(() => airport.CallAirTrafficControl());
        }
    }
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58998834/how-to-use-ifixture-buildt-with-automoqcustomization-when-t-is-an-interface
    public class AutoMoqInvalidAirportDataAttribute : AutoDataAttribute
    {
        public static Func<IFixture> fixtureFactory = () =>
        {
            IFixture f = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
            f.RepeatCount = 5;
    // How do you set MULTIPLE properties?
    // How does one use the default AutoFixture values rather than leaving the uninitialized values as null?
    // Can one pass a custom property used earlier in the Fixture creation process to another custom property used later?
    f.Customize<Mock<IAirport>>(c => c.Do(m => m.SetupGet(i => i.code).Returns("NOT")));
            return f;
        };
        public AutoMoqInvalidAirportDataAttribute() : base(fixtureFactory)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

AutoFixture does not populate mock properties by default, but it can be done. These blog posts describe how to do it:

https://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/04/05/how-to-configure-automoq-to-set-up-all-properties/

https://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/04/08/how-to-automatically-populate-properties-with-automoq/

Author of AutoFixture does not recommend this approach, however, as he considers declaration of properties in interfaces a design smell. 
I could not find the original discussion about this topic unfortunately, but it is hidden somewhere on StackOverflow in the comments. Maybe you will be able to find it if you go through Mark Seemann's profile.